# Using textfile in a combo box

Tags: java, swing, file-io, input, jcombobox

Hello I've been having trouble getting my combo box to list items from a textfile. And while I'm at it could I want to ask if my radioButton change dynamically when I change my combobx or will that be too much trouble?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MovieSelection extends JFrame {

private JRadioButton selection1;
private JRadioButton selection2;
private JRadioButton selection3;
private JPanel moviePanel;
private JLabel priceLabel;

private JComboBox movieBox;
private ButtonGroup bg;

private String[] movieName = { "RED", "Taken", "Star Trek", "Star Wars",
        "Avatar" };


public MovieSelection() {
    super("Please select your movie");
    setSize(800, 400);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(15, 4));

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(TheMovies.txt);
    buildMoviePanel();

    add(moviePanel);

    setVisible(true);

}



private class MovieLists implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(TheMovies.txt);

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            String nextMovieName = inputFile.nextLine();

        }

        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String Themovie = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You want complete text file in a combo box ?

Comment: Can you find any errors in this line `Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(TheMovies.txt);` in the `actionPerformed` method

Comment: Also `JComboBox movieLists = new JComboBox(TheMovies.txt);`

Comment: This ***[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File))*** would help you.

Comment: Apurv yes  and the only errors are at TheMovies.txt which I find weird  because the file does exist. This is driving me up the wall I might see if I can find a way using arrayyLists. Is that any better?

Comment: You should be specific about *what* actually fails. I assume that in your case the code failed to compile, for reasons I'll post below. But letting others do that guesswork is a waste of everybody's time!

Answer (score 1):

You're writing `TheMovies.txt` as an expression, so the java compiler will look for a class called `TheMovies` containing a public static member called `txt`.

What you really meant was a string literal, so you have to enclose it in quotation marks:

```
"TheMovies.txt"
```

But when you pass a `String` to the [`Scanner` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29), that string itself will be scanned, and not interpreted as a file name. So you have to construct a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) object from that string first.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("TheMovies.txt"));
```

The line

```
JComboBox movieLists = new JComboBox(TheMovies.txt);
```

is wrong for the same reason of being interpreted as an expression. Not sure what your intention here is in any case, but I hope you can find your own next steps from this. It should be something along the lines of iterating over the file content and filling the combo box one item at a time.